# Comma after last author field in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

Currently, my `references` (not citations) have no comma between the last author name, e.g.

```
Author, AB, CD Author 2012
Author, AB, CD Author et al. 2012
```

What I would like is:

```
Author, AB, CD Author, 2012
Author, AB, CD Author et al., 2012
```

As requested here are the options, I have provided to biblatex:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear-icomp,
citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
uniquename=false,
uniquelist=false, 
firstinits=true, 
maxbibnames=5,
minbibnames=5, 
maxcitenames=2,
mincitenames=1, 
sorting=ynt, 
url=false, 
isbn=false, 
eprint=false, 
doi=false, 
dashed=false, 
natbib=true,
ibidtracker=false,
backend=biber]{biblatex}

%Remove comma in (Beadle and Tautum, 1941) This applies to citation only
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

Comment: Could you give more information, for example what options do you provide to the `biblatex` package, and what commands you use for that output?

Comment: I have updated the post to show all biblatex options.

Comment: And how do you produce the "references"? Your output doesn't look like anything you can find in http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/examples/53-style-authoryear-icomp.pdf .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is use the `xpatch` package to patch the `date+extrayear` bibmacro as follows:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\unspace\addcomma\addspace}{}{}
```

EDIT: Here is an explanation of the patch. The `biblatex` documentation contains a `bib latex.def` file with definitions of many bibmacro and other aspects, covering among other which and when bib fields are printed and formatting instructions to print them. Then `biblatex` include `standards.blx`. In this file there are the definitions of the drivers. The definition of the drivers specify the order of the various elements. The date/year does not appear directly in the main drivers, but it appears in biblatex macros. For example, for the `authoryear` style it appears in the macro that produce the author(s)/editor(s) (and the `authoryear-icomp` calls the `authoryear` style (for references).

Comment: Guido: That does work, thanks.  However, I am not quite sure how.  How does the field 'date+extrayear' refer to a place between the last author's name and the year?

Comment: In `biblatex` v3.8 `date+extrayear` was renamed to `date+extradate`, so this would need to be changed in newer versions for this to work. But with `biblatex` 3.8 and newer I would recommend `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` as in my answer below anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case someone is still interested in this in 2018.

This is now easily possible using `biblatex`'s context-sensitive delimiters with

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

Comment: Commenting here so I can save myself a lot of time and trouble the next time it need this. Spent hours searching. Thank you so much for this.